# Pinescript, financial(FLOAT_SHARES_OUTSTANDING) value is different than its corresponding float shares screener value

Tags: plot, pine-script, finance

in my script I plot the symbol float shares with the classic financial method:

```
floatShares = financial(syminfo.tickerid, "FLOAT_SHARES_OUTSTANDING", "FY")
```

For some symbols, it is different than its corresponding float shares value in the screener.

Here is an example from FUTU:

[image]

Why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the screener you look on `Total Shares Outstanding`. `Float Shares` column caption is `FLOAT`.
2. Screener shows value of float shares for today / yestaday.
3. In your pine script there are you request `Float Shares` with FY periodicy, i.e. Float Shares at end of last fiscal year.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot with the correct one. My bad. Is there a way to retrieve programmatically the float shares for today/yesterday?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible now (